# Can multidimensional arrays cause 403 forbidden errors?

Tags: php, hash, multidimensional-array, http-status-code-403, server

Let's say I have a php hash with questions as the keys to subhashes that have answers as the keys to their correctness values:

```
$questions = array(
    //1
    "What?" => array(
        "Answer A" => "false", 
        "Answer B" => "false", 
        "Answer C" => "true", 
        "Answer D" => "false", 
        "expl" => "**C is the correct answer."//also holds the explanations of these questions
    ),
    "When?" => array(
        "Answer A" => "false", 
        "Answer B" => "false", 
        "Answer C" => "false", 
        "Answer D" => "true", 
        "expl" => "**D is the correct answer, because..."
     ),

    ...
    ...
    ...

    //12
    "How?" => array(
        "Answer A" => "true", 
        "Answer B" => "false", 
        "Answer C" => "false", 
        "Answer D" => "false", 
        "expl" => "**A is the correct answer."
    )
);
```

I want to output only a subsequence of these questions based on what a user's previous information using this function:

```
function checkpoint($type){
    global $questions;

    //defined the subsequences for each type
    $sub1 = array(1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 10, 8, 11, 12);
    $sub2 = array(1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 10, 8, 11, 12);
    $sub3 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 6, 10, 7, 8);

    switch($type){
        case 1: $questionpath = $sub1; break;
        case 2: $questionpath = $sub2; break;
        default: $questionpath = $sub3; 
    }

    $q_strings = array_keys($questions);
    $letters = range('A', 'Z');

    //output
    for($i = 0; $i < count($questionpath); $i++){

        $qnum = $questionpath[$i] - 1; //the index of the question
        $question = array_keys($questions)[$qnum];
        $answers = array_keys($questions[$question]);


        echo '<table><tr><td>'.($i+1).'</td>
              <td>'.$question.'</td>
              </tr></table>';

        for($j = 0; $j < count($answers); $j++){
             if($answers[$j] != "expl")
             echo '<input type="radio" name="q'.($i+1).'" id="q'.($i+1).'a'.($j+1).'" onchange="showAnswer($(\'#correct'.($i+1).'\'),'.$questions[$question][$answers[$j]].');"><label for="q'.($i+1).'a'.($j+1).'">'.range('A', 'Z')[$j].'. '.$answers[$j].'</label></br />';
        }

        echo '<span id="correct'.($i+1).'" class="correct"><i>'.$questions[$question]['expl'].'</i></span>
        <span class="correct"><i>'.$questions[$question]['expl'].'</i></span>
        </div>
        <br />';
    }

}
```

Having this function in a ".inc" file has worked on my local server, but having it on a live server causes 403 errors.

However, changing the code so that there wouldn't be multidimensional access like so:

```
$q_arr = $questions[$question];
```

and changing accesses as:

```
$questions[$question][$answers[$j]]
```

to something like:

```
 $q_arr[$ans]
```

has fixed these 403 errors. So, is it possible that servers can give 403 errors just by having code that accesses a multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Are you positive this is all that you changed? Are you sure you didn't change the file permissions of the include file when you made these changes? Failing code would cause an error, but it shouldn't cause a 403.

Comment: @A.Duff yes, I did not even change the file permissions at all.